# Is it possible to change the default schema?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to change the default schema in a database so that I don't have to change it manually every time?  Currently it defaults to 'dbo'.  I have a lot of tables to set up and it's annoying to have to change for each table.

Comment: The default schema can be changed per user. But if you are using multiple schemas it is best to be explicit and use the schema name.

Comment: Multiple schemas or not, it's better to *always* specify the schema.

Comment: Its even more annoying to support/maintain code developed using a different default schema.  You should always specify the schema.  If your developers are in the habit of not specifying, make their default schema one in which they cannot create objects.  That way, they'll always have to specify the schema, for DDL & DML statements.

Comment: Yes.  While it's arguably fine to use non-schema-qualified names when referencing objects in the same schema from static SQL in stored procedures and views, application developers should normally use schema-qualified names in DDL.  A user created for a Windows Group will, by default, not have a default schema, so if your DBA hasn't explicitly set one, SQL will provision you a private schema when you create an object with an unqualified name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can on a user level either in the user mapping of the database in SSMS or with [T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql):

```
ALTER USER UserName WITH DEFAULT_SCEHMA = SchemaName
```